# Remove local core changes after testing

Tags: magento-1.6, core

I've made a change to App.php in /app/local/Mage/Core/Model to test something, but now when removing the file the, the site gives a fatal error! - I've cleard the cache files but didn't help?

```
Warning: include(/var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/App.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/site.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Core/Model/App.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/local:/var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/community:/var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/core:/var/www/site.com/public_html/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/site.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Core_Model_App' not found in /var/www/site.com/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 633
```

Comment: You can change the core files for testing purposes. Especially if the core is under version control you can just revert the files. But be careful, don't commit them :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are a couple of things to try:

- Manually delete the `var/cache` folder contents.
- Check you don't have compilation enabled
- Check that you don't have `APC` enabled
- Check the `App.php` still exists under `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model` and that you didn't accidentally changed the content.

From your error log:

```
Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Core/Model/App.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/local:/var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/community:/var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/core:/var/www/site.com/public_html/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/site.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

Magento is telling you that it can't find the App Model in any of the code pools, most likely something happend to the original App.php file

Comment: I like your answer better than mine. It covers more error sources. :) +1.

Comment: The original file is still in it's correct position, just checked :) I've tried to remove the var/cache folder and no luck. Compiler is disabled and the includes folder is deleted. I don't think the server is using APC, can I check this?

Comment: I tried changing the local/core file, and hench forth came another error, but this time it told me some old fpc extension was enabled, so I messed around some files and found an fpc xml file in the /etc/ folder, renamed it to .sample, and then it worked! - for now :)

Comment: Interesting, glad to hear is working now

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the original file `App.php` exists in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model`. Also if you have compilation enabled disabled it.